# How get Multiple Checkbox value in Controller submitted from the form in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have the table with each row containing checkbox where checkbox value is set as id from the database. How can i access them to controller to update in database. I have tried to dump the value in my controller but it show NULL.
Here is my view:

```
<form  action= "po" method="POST" >
 @csrf

 <input type="submit" name="submit">
      <div class="table-responsive">

        <table class="table custom-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">
                <label class="control control--checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="js-check-all"/>
                  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                </label>
              </th>
              <th scope="col" >S.N</th>
              <th scope="col">LC NO</th>
              <th scope="col">Applicant</th>
              <th scope="col">Doc Value</th>
              <th scope="col">Doc Received date</th>
              <th scope="col">LC Type</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php $number = 1;?>
            @foreach($datas as $items)
              
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" style="padding:20px">
                <label class="control control--checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist[]" value="{{$items->id}}" />
                  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                </label>
              </th>
              <td>{{$number}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->lc_no}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->applicant}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->doc_value}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->rec_date}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->sight_usance}}</td>
            </tr>
            <?php $number++; ?>
            @endforeach
         
            
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </form>
```

Here is my Controller

```
 function po(Request $req){

        dd($req->chekboxlist);


    }
```

Comment: have you checked checkbox or else it return null.To avoid that you need to add  validation

Comment: Ya i checked chekbox...And how can i add validation...

Comment: is it still returning null after clicking checkbox

Comment: Yes!! @JohnLobo still returning null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing wrong key from Request `$req->chekboxlist`

But it should be

```
$req->checkboxlist
```

Always add Validation to Avoid erorrs while saving data

```
 $validate=Validator::make($request->all(), [
            "checkboxlist"    => "required|array",
           

        ]);
if($validate->fails()){
  return redirect()->back()->with("errors",$validate->errors());
}
```